# How to match list of IP addresses to a list of Subnets?

Tags: list, networking, network-programming, ip, firewall

I am working on a script that takes the input of servers and converts them to IPs and matches that IP to a subnet from my firewall.
I have the ns lookup portion done and it converts user inputed servers into IPs and returns them into a list.
I pulled routing info from my firewall which brings back a list of networks.

What I would like to do is have both lists compare and match IPs to Subnets.

10.10.0.123 - 10.10.0.0/24
192.168.10.3 - 192.168.10.0/24

the lists are unequal as i may only have a few IPs that need to match against all the networks on a given firewall.

I would want the output to only include the number of IPs rather than giving out any errors and outputting the entire list of networks as well. Just the ones that match.

Thanks for any help in advance but I am having trouble comparing each list and I can't seem to find any useful info from my web searches.

Comment: You need to mask the address with the network mask, and if the result is equal to the network, the address is in the network. [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains about that, and that is how network devices and hosts determine if an address is in a network. Do not make the mistake of trying to do this with the text representation of IPv4 addressing, you must use the native (binary) IPv4 addressing.

Comment: i was thinking it would be simpler as I am maybe only trying to match the first 2 or 3 octets from 2 lists I already have pulled

Comment: Octets have nothing to do with IPv4 addressing. The dotted decimal notation is simply to make it easier for humans to read an IPv4 address. IPv4 addresses are 32-bit unsigned integers, and that is how you need to use them for something like this. Network devices only see them as the binary format. You should actually store them in the lists as binary, and only convert to the dotted-decimal notation when presenting to a human to read.

Comment: so i can't run a comparison of the lists and say an ip of 10.30.2.100 is in the ip list and the network 10.30.2.0/24 is in the networks list... I can't just say well these match up to 10.30.2 lets print, 10.30.2.100 and 10.30.2.0/24 on the same line?

Comment: What if the prefix length is 23 or 25? The octets mean nothing, and you could be incorrect because the network extends into the middle of an octet. You should at least read the first part of the answer I linked above.